# Running in Background

Tags: android, battery

Hi I have  simple question
I need to run my app in the background when the screen is locked.
Using service is the only way? Its seems complicated for my simple program.
( i'm writing simple gps logger which must be logging even if user blocked the phone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the only way. Use a normal `Service`, you can also make it `sticky` to let is restart itself when `Android` kills it because of low resources.

Use `startService` to start is. If you are using `bindService` it will stop the `Service` when the `Activity` is killed. You probably don't want that.
Don't forget to call `stopService` when you don't want to use the Service anymore.

`IntentService` is not suitable because it will stop itself when done.